# Texmaker "! Extra \endgroup." compiling error

Tags: latex, miktex, texmaker

I have installed Miktex and Texmaker and am trying to compile a very simple tex file:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn]{revtex4} 
\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

but I am getting the error on the `\begin{document}` line "!Extra\endgroup.\document->\endgroup\init@documenthook\set@typesize@hook\normalsize\set... \begin{document}". The error: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18yXl.png) .The pdf shows:[latex pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROHh5.png)

Here is the .log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.12) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.1.16)  16 JAN 2021 17:56
entering extended mode
**./test_2.tex
(test_2.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-01-09> xparse <2020-03-03>
(E:\Miktex\tex/latex/revtex4\revtex4.cls
Document Class: revtex4 2001/08/03 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for do
cumentation)
 Copyright (c) 2001 The American Physical Society.
 mailto:revtex@aps.org
 Licensed under the LPPL:
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/lppl.txt
 Arthur Ogawa <ogawa@teleport.com>
 Based on work by David Carlisle <david@dcarlisle.demon.co.uk>.
ltxutil: portions licensed from W. E. Baxter (web@superscript.com)
Class revtex4 Info: Repairing broken LateX \@sect on input line 596.
\intertabularlinepenalty=\count177
\@tbpen=\count178
\@arstrutbox@hline=\box47
Class revtex4 Info: Repairing broken LaTeX \@xbitor on input line 1610.
ltxgrid: portions licensed from W. E. Baxter (web@superscript.com)
\c@linecount=\count179
\output=\toks15
\@protection@box=\box48
\@topmark@saved=\toks16
\footins@saved=\box49
\pagesofar=\box50
\footbox=\box51
\pagegrid@col=\count180
Class revtex4 Info: Incorporating package {textcase}  [1998/11/12 v0.06 Text on
ly upper/lower case changing (DPC)]. on input line 3682.
(E:\Miktex\tex/latex/url\url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
\c@affil=\count181
\absbox=\box52
\c@part=\count182
\c@section=\count183
\c@subsection=\count184
\c@subsubsection=\count185
\c@paragraph=\count186
\c@subparagraph=\count187
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\c@figure=\count188
\c@table=\count189
 (E:\Miktex\tex/latex/natbib\natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip49
\bibsep=\skip50
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count190
)
\widetext@top=\box53
\widetext@bot=\box54

(E:\Miktex\tex/latex/revtex4\revsymb.sty
Package: revsymb 2001/08/03 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documenta
tion)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \REV@mathfrak on input line 118.
))

Class revtex4 Warning: No Society specified, using generic APS style.

(E:\Miktex\tex/latex/revtex4\aps.rtx
File: aps.rtx 2001/08/03 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documentatio
n)
) (E:\Miktex\tex/latex/revtex4\10pt.rtx
File: 10pt.rtx 2001/08/03 v4.0 (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documentati
on)
)
! Extra \endgroup.
\document ->\endgroup 
                      \init@documenthook \set@typesize@hook \normalsize \set...
l.2 \begin{document}
                    
Things are pretty mixed up, but I think the worst is over.


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.2 \begin{document}
                    
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

(E:\Miktex\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2021-01-09 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count191
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box55
) (test_2.aux)
\openout1 = `test_2.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.
Class revtex4 Info: Unrecognized LaTeX tabular. Please update this document cla
ss! (Proceeding with fingers crossed.) on input line 2.
Class revtex4 Info: cite was not loaded (OK!) on input line 2.
Class revtex4 Info: multicol was not loaded (OK!) on input line 2.
 [1{C:/Users/l04sa/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (test_2.aux)
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1949 strings out of 479618
 26287 string characters out of 2881546
 304780 words of memory out of 3000000
 19187 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 403430 words of font info for 27 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 53i,4n,60p,192b,111s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<E:/Miktex/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test_2.pdf (1 page, 13928 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 10 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

I am really not sure why I am getting this, would appreciate any help. Let me know if you need more info on my setup. Thank you

Comment: Your minimal working example works fine for me. Can you show the .log file so I can check if we maybe have some different version of a package or something like that?

Comment: How can I post the file? It is too long to post as text

Comment: It should only have about 120 lines, so should be well within the limits to edit your question to add it. Alternatively you could use something like pastebin.com or github

Comment: Have edited it in now.

Comment: Your revtex4 version is pretty old. Try with `revtex4 2020/09/30 v4.0a`

Comment: What is that exactly and how can I update it? I am surprised I have old versions as I downloaded miktex and texmaker today.

Comment: That sounds strange. Let me check with somebody who uses miktex, if it has the current revtex4 version.

Comment: please have a look at https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56770140#56770140 and following messages

Comment: Thanks for friends' help and quick replies!! How can I replace the old revtex4 with revtex4.2 so that it will be compatible? Does the log file not require a file called revtex.cls which will not be included?

Comment: You can use `\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn]{revtex4-2} ` to get the new class

Comment: Okay I did not manage copy over the right cls files or create new folders but I managed to install a new package and it appears to be working now. Thank you so much for your help samcarter

Answer (score 0):

I add one line "\RequirePackage[2020-02-02]{latexrelease}" before "\documentcall[a4]{seminar}" and it works.  I do not know why. I am no expert at all.

\RequirePackage[2020-02-02]{latexrelease}
\documentclass[a4]{seminar}